# Is that possible to use canvas element in DOM jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, dom

I am new to jquery.

Is that possible to add canvas class in DOM jquery?
The canvas class include Skycons's icons that I want to use for my api.

```
 $.ajax ({
 url: "url",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(e) {

       let icon = e.weather[0].icon;
          switch (icon) {
            case "01d":
              icon = "CLEAR_DAY";
              break;
            case "01n":
              icon = "CLEAR_NIGHT";
              break;
            case "02d":
              icon = "PARTLY_CLOUDY_DAY";
              break;
            case "02n":
              icon = "PARTLY_CLOUDY_NIGHT";
              break;
            case "03d":
              icon = "CLOUDY";
              break;
            case "03n":
              icon = "CLOUDY";
              break;
            case "04d":
              icon = "CLOUDY";
              break;
            case "04n":
              icon = "CLOUDY";
              break;
            case "09d":
              icon = "RAIN";
             break;
            case "09n":
              icon = "RAIN";
              break;
            case "10d":
              icon = "RAIN";
              break;
            case "10n":
              icon = "RAIN";
              break;
            case "11d":
              icon = "RAIN";
              break;
            case "11n":
              icon = "RAIN";
              break;
            case "13d":
              icon = "SNOW";
              break;
            case "13n":
              icon = "SNOW";
              break;
            case "50d":
              icon = "FOG";
              break;
            case "50n":
              icon = "FOG";
              break;
          }
```

Then adding function

```
 setIcons(icon, document.querySelector(".icon"));

        function setIcons(icon, iconID) {
          const skycons = new Skycons({ color: "white" });
          const currentIcon = icon;
           skycons.play();
         return skycons.set(iconID, Skycons[currentIcon]);
      }
    let variable ='';

    variable += '<div class="row h-100">';
    variable += '   <canvas class="icon" width="128" height="128"></canvas>';        
    variable += '</div>';

    $('#letWeather').html(variable);

 }
});
```

Then add this id to Html..

```
<div id="letWeather"></div>
```

It doesn't displaying...

But if I am adding this to HTML, outside of DOM. It does works. Why?

```
<canvas class="icon" width="128" height="128"></canvas>
```

Comment: it is most likely because `let` is a [reserved keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#reserved_keywords_as_of_ecmascript_2015) and cannot be reassigned. You should see an error thrown in browser console.

Comment: "*is it possible to [add] a canvas element [using] jquery*" - yes, sure it is.  Make sure you run your jquery code either in doc.ready (wrap it inside `$(function() { ...here ... })` or that your code runs after the `letWeather` element is on the page.

Comment: Here's your code working fine in a doc.ready:  https://jsfiddle.net/Lr1ufa6y/1/  (not that jsfiddle puts the code at the end anyway)

Comment: Regarding `let` as a variable name: I would certainly consider a different name, but you *can* use it as a variable name without issue.   `let = ''` is the same as `window.let = ''` and you can also do `var let = ''` but you **can't** do `let let = ''`

Comment: I edited my post. It wasn't wrong with let. I know how this works..

Comment: Freedomn-n Nice fiddle but I am using ajax to get api values and I am sure that I can't just add a function there between.

Comment: "*I'm using ajax to get...*" - there's no indication of that in your code.   It's unclear how "*get api values*" has anything to do with your question.  Please update to include relevant information.

Comment: Essentially, you can't add an element to another element if that 2nd element does exist at the time you try to add it (which it sounds like you're trying to do).

Comment: Edited my post. Maybe easier to read now?

Comment: You have a massive pile of code marked up as a *quote*, you are way more items then is needed in the switch statement to make your point, it isn't clear where the call to `setIcons` fits with regard to the rest of the code. Try providing a [mcve]. Look at the live demo feature of the question editor.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the *order* you are doing things in.

First you search the DOM for an element with the class `icon` and you do *stuff* with whatever you find.

Next you create a string with some HTML in it that includes an element with that class.

Finally you use that HTML to add that element to the DOM.

---

You aren't going to find it if you search the DOM for it **before** you add it to the DOM.

Comment: Might to be nice if u would like to explain little more for me. What do you mean that I'm not going to find it.

Comment: I mean that if you take a blank piece of paper, read out what is written on it, then write "this is an icon" then the words you will have read out will be "" and not "this is an icon".

Comment: Reverse the order of the three steps.